# How can Symfony2 be configured to only set a cookie if logged in?

Tags: symfony, varnish

- A page must be configured within a Symfony2 firewall for
  Symfony2 to detect if a user is logged in (the page can still allow
  non logged in users)
- All pages within a Symfony2 firewall are sending PHPSESSID cookies.
- Caching applications must **only** cache the version of the page
  non logged in users get.
- Caching applications determine whether a user is logged in and
  getting unique content by checking if a cookie is set

Most of my users are not logged in.  How can I configure Symfony2 to not send a cookie until a user sends a cookie or starts a new login session?

Edge Side Includes will not help.  Using ESI there is still a portion of the page that goes to a Controller unprotected by the cache, so the whole Symfony2 system is fired up needlessly for anonymous requests that should just be fired from the cache.

Comment: Set a extra cookie in the interactive login event and use it for determining caching.

Comment: @Pazi - that's a great idea.  It might get a little tricky working with two different cache products (varnish local, plus load balancer) and setting up complicated rules so cookies expire when sessions expire, and so logged in users can still get cached pages when going to common areas.  But it would work.